# I got "Application Error" in heroku while app deployment

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

After typing "git push heroku master" I got this as output:

[image]

When I visited the URL for an app hosted on heroku, I got this display:

[image]

After reviewing logs by typing "heroku logs --tail", it displayed this:

[image]

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with toml package or whatever it is, there is an error that says TomlDecoderError: key name found without value, Reached end of line. (Line 1 column 25 char 25), you need to double check it

this error has to do with your code but not really related to heroku. Apologies if my English is not clear Buddy

Comment: actually, i double checked my code which i am trying to deploy. So according to you would the error be present in setup.sh file or the Procfile ?

Comment: Try to run it in production first on your machine before deploying to heroku, that way you can see if it will throw an error, from the error shown on the pic, its your application error not really heroku's error.

Comment: double the setup.js Procfile doesn't really has much of the problem

Comment: I ran the production on my localhost on port 8501, it is running perfectly.

Comment: Okay that means everything is fine but only on your machine, So now you need to double check your file/folder naming because heroku runs on Linux and Linux is very sensitive for example if you have a folder name *Folder* on your machine, locally you may access it like this "folder/index.js" but on heroku it will not work, so make sure you check all your file/folder naming